# what is the use of integers.xml in android

Tags: android, performance

User can make the class in which he can declare the integers as static final int.
So, what is the use of integers.xml in android. Because android is also compile them and put it in R.java as static variable.

So, what is the use of integers.xml and which method is gives better performance either to make a class and put the variable as static final int or declared it inn integers.xml

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> what is the use of integers.xml

You might have different values for the integer to be used in different device configurations: different screen size, different API level, different keyboard type, etc.

> which method is gives better performance either to make a class and put the variable as static final int or declared it inn integers.xml

For pure performance, you cannot beat `static final int FOO=1;`. The objective of integer resources, like all resources, is less on performance and more on moving configuration-related logic out of Java code and into resources.

Answer (score 0):

They are useful because it lets you redefine constants without having to do any code changes.

Furthermore since they are resources they can be defined differently for different device sizes and configurations such as API level and keyboard type.

```
static final int MY_CONST = 3;
```

is going to have the best performance, but you should write code for readability until you identify areas that need a performance improvement.